# relation " " does not exist in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a doubt what does it mean:

```
relation "clientes" does not exist
LINE 1: select nombre from Clientes where joindate between "2022-02-...
```

It seems strange to me; or that this error appears since my model is called Customers; I just did the migrations on heroku, but I get this error

> In my views I have this:

```
def list_clientes(request):


    if request.method == 'POST':
        fromdate=request.POST.get('fromdate')
        todate = request.POST.get('todate')
        searchresult=Clientes.objects.raw('select nombre from Clientes where joindate between "'+fromdate+'" and "'+todate+'"')
        return render(request,'Clientes/clientes-list.html',{'clientes':searchresult})

    else:
        displaydata = Clientes.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'Clientes/clientes-list.html', {'clientes': displaydata})
```

> models.py

```
class Clientes(models.Model):
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    fecha_registro = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.nombre}'
```

> settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME':'sistemacarros_db',
        'USER':'postgres',
        'PASSWORD':'1234',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':'5432',
        'OPTIONS':{
            'init_command':"SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'",
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In django, the actual database table name isn't just the model name; it usually includes the app name also.  So the table name wouldn't be `clientes`, it would be something like `myapp_clientes`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use the Django ORM:

```
def list_clientes(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fromdate=request.POST.get('fromdate')
        todate = request.POST.get('todate')
        searchresult = Clientes.objects.filter(fecha_registro__range=(fromdate, todate))
    else:
        searchresult = Clientes.objects.all()
    return render(request,'Clientes/clientes-list.html',{'clientes':searchresult})
```

---

> **Note**: Django's [**`DateTimeField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField)
> has a [**`auto_now_add=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField.auto_now_add)
> to work with timestamps. This will automatically assign the current datetime
> when creating the object, and mark it as non-editable (`editable=False`), such
> that it does not appear in `ModelForm`s by default.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I only get this error Cannot resolve keyword 'joindate' into field. Choices are...and it puts everything I have in models, only I can't put it here because it would be a lot of code

Comment: @AnaidBracho: ah, likely it is `fecha_registro` instead.